# How to link pages in Node

Tags: node.js, routes

I have a  page index.html which loads when I run app.js, in App.js I have:

```
app.get('/branch', function (req, res,html) {
res.render('/reacted/branch.html');
});
```

I have 
    `<li>
    <a href="branch.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-table"></i> Branches</a>
                    </li>`
When I click on Branches on the menu, I want branch.html to render

Comment: Check out expressjs.com it's node.js framework with support for routing

Comment: would it allow me to run scripts on click?

Comment: No express is for server side, but if you click a link in browser express can serve the HTML page

Comment: Okay tried this but It just displays branch.html on the webpage, does take me to the page `app.get('/branch.html', function (req, res) {
  res.send('branch.html');
});
`

Comment: Can you post some code or explain  more clearly what you are trying do do?

Comment: Can you please help now?

Comment: OK if the branch.html is static file which you don't add any dynamic content to then place it to public directory this requires use of express-static middleware tho and you don't even need app.get to serve it. If it's dynamic then you need to setup view engine and point it to folder with your HTML files and use res.render('branch') to serve it

Answer (score 3):

I just needed to do this in my html file:

```
<a href="/branch"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-table"></i> Branches</a>
```

and this in js file:

```
app.get('/branch', function (req, res,html) {
 res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/branch.html'));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to create APIs for serving static pages (Unless you are not rendering them).

Express provide a great functionality for serving static files (Of any file extension). All you need to do is to add following middleware in your server file (app.js/server.js):

> app.use(express.static(__dirname));
>
> a href="/branch.html"

Adding file extension in href will work

Comment: I was trying to move onto MVC from here, as I don't want to repeat my navbar on each page, I just want a section that gets rendered when I click my menu